# Issues with getBoundingClientRect on Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I have been playing around with a website built on Angular Material and I found a cool pen on codepen.io which has a tall toolbar with that shrinks to a smaller one, while changing from having a background image to a solid color. You can see the example if you click on the link below:
[Angular material alpha toolbar - codepen](http://codepen.io/jbltx/pen/KwQxBX)

PS: The image seems to not be hosted anymore, so it's a blank div.

This code works fine in Safari when looking at the example on Codepen, however on my local site the md-toolbar only has a height of 181px which makes the content below the toolbar overlap.

I've looked around the code and the issue seems to be with getBoundingClientRect which when entered in the console like this:

```
document.querySelector('[md-page-header]').getBoundingClientRect()
```

returns all values as undefined. So bottom, left, right, top, width and height are all undefined. However, if I do the following:

```
document.querySelector('[md-page-header]').getBoundingClientRect().height
```

I get the correct value for the height of the element.

I have looked around on Google for answers but couldn't find anything relevant. Could anyone explain why this could be happening and if there is some way to fix this?